# How to fx low FPS in a single threaded Directx9 3D game

Tags: rendering, multithreading, directx9, lag

We're having issues with low FPS in a third-person shooter 3D game. This happens when you have too many polygons on screen. The FPS is locked to 60, and the gameplay is fine, but the moment when you have like 900 entities on screen, the FPS immediately drops to 45 or 50.

`IDirect3DDevice9::DrawIndexedPrimitive` is normally called 200-900 times to render the entities, however, when you render more polygons than usual, let's say 500,000 more vertices then it's called 6000-7000 times and the FPS drops to 45-50. I ran a profiler and saw this function eating up the CPU, consuming around 19% of the resources.

I have some ideas to deal this issue, but I need some advice. Possible solutions that I can think of:

**Secondary thread for rendering**

I'm not sure if introducing multi-threading will fix the problem, but I'm hopeful.

**Upgrading to Directx11**

If this can help, then can someone explain how we need to render the vertex buffers of entites? This how we do it now for every entity:

```
d3dDevice->Clear(0,NULL,D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255,255,255),1.0f,0);

// Turn on wireframe mode
d3dDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_FILLMODE,D3DFILL_WIREFRAME);
d3dDevice->BeginScene();

for (DWORD i=0; i<numMaterials; i++)
{
    // Set the material and texture for this subset
    d3dDevice->SetMaterial(&meshMaterials[i]);
    d3dDevice->SetTexture(0,meshTextures[i]);

    // Draw the mesh subset
    mesh->DrawSubset( i );
}

d3dDevice->EndScene();
d3dDevice->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

**Both**

Upgrade to Directx11 and use a secondary thread for rendering?

Comment: Because I don't currently have the time to write examples, I won't post this as an answer. I think you should take a look at "instancing". Basically, it allows you to draw the same thing in different places in a single draw call.

Comment: @Peethor That sounds like a good idea, but what if the objects have different geometries? We're not using instancing atm, we'll use it for rendering trees.

Comment: Different geometry == different draw calls. But in many games, you'd be drawing things like scenery (trees, boxes, tables) a lot. Having one draw call per model instead of one draw call per object can save a lot of time.

Comment: You're right. That makes sense. I guess this is the answer then.

Comment: Feel free to add it as such for future reference when you've got something working!

Comment: Yeah, I will, and I'll also try to add a secondary thread and check the performance then. I'll let you know here. Thank you.

Comment: Does every mesh have its own material? This is gong to be a problem. Like instancing, you could look at batching to reduce the amount of draw calls.

Comment: @Jay No. Majority of the entities have exactly the same mesh with same materials and textures. How is batching better than instancing? I though it was the same thing, for instance, https://github.com/widmoser/lotus/blob/ca55f292e62bf5da068b3f7c1d007e590b1a6f72/engine/DXRenderer/dxbatch.cpp#L219

Comment: @Jay I did some research to understand how to properly implement batching of vertex buffers. The basic idea is to insert triangles from meshes into one vertex buffer if they have the same texture and render the texture in one draw call. If this is what you meant, it is can excellent idea. Thanks :)

Comment: Generally you want to keep the total number of draw calls per frame for Direct3D 9 to 2000-3000 for a good FPS. There's a lot of hidden perf costs with Direct3D 9 which is one of the reasons Direct3D 10+ was designed a lot differently.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I see, that makes sense. We're planning to upgrade to DX11 by next year. For now, I decided to use textures atlases to reduce draw calls and batching along with instancing. DirectXTex was really helpful, and it made things easier, so thanks for that.